# Multiple subdomain contexts for drupal

Tags: drupal

The project I am working on wants to split up the site into regions via subdomains, for example:

- usa.domain
- za.domain
- ke.domain

Each subdomain would have it's own content (news, about, etc), and then the main domain site would show content (news) from all the sub domains.

What would be the best way to achieve this using Drupal? Would I be able to use Drupal 8 for this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out.

I ended up installing the [Domain Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) which works exactly as I expected a solution like this to work.

Once you have it installed, and set up a few domain records in the configuration adding content to specific domains is as simple as clicking a checkbox.

A cool note is that the menu structure plays along nicely with this module too, although that might just be clever Drupal.

I used Drupal 8 and even though this module doesn't have an official release yet, it works perfectly.